# Outofbound error on word Array program

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
   This class prints the numeric value of a letter grade given by the user.
*/
public class Words
{
    int i=0;
    String[] wordz;
    /**
        Constructs words class
    */
    public Words()
    {
        wordz= new String[5];
    }

    /**
        collects 5 words from user and places then into array
        @return the gradeValue
    */
    public void inputArray(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e)
    {
        wordz = new String[] { a, b, c, d, e };
    }

    /**
        counts even and odds
        @return numeric grade
     */
    public void removeShortWords()
    {
        ArrayList<String> wordzList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(wordz));
        for(i=0; i < wordz.length; i++)
        {

            if(wordz[i].length() < 3)
                wordzList.remove(i);//out of bounds error here

            String[] wordz = wordzList.toArray(new String[wordzList.size()]);
        }
    }

    /**
        prints out the array of 10 positive integers
        @return numeric grade
     */
    public void printArray()
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(wordz));
    }
}
```

This is my tester class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordPrgm {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Words wordArray = new Words();
        System.out.println("PLease enter five words");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String w1 = in.nextLine();
        String w2 = in.nextLine();
        String w3 = in.nextLine();
        String w4 = in.nextLine();
        String w5 = in.nextLine();
        wordArray.inputArray(w1, w2, w3, w4, w5);
        wordArray.removeShortWords();
        wordArray.printArray();
    }
}
```

The program here is supposed to remove word that are less than 3 letters from an array and print out the new words. I've been looking through the code again and again but I don't see where the solution is and what I'm missing. I think the for loop may be messed up or something. Thank you!

I keep getting an error at this point in the program.

```
wordzList.remove(i);
```

Comment: Less than five? Looks more like three to me.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that I wasn't thinking, it should be less than 3, not five.

Comment: @javaProgrammer if answer is helped you don't forget to accept it

Answer (score 2):

```
 ArrayList<String> wordzList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(wordz));
for(i=0; i < wordz.length; i++)
{

    if(wordz[i].length() < 3)
        wordzList.remove(i);//out of bounds error here

    String[] wordz = wordzList.toArray(new String[wordzList.size()]);
}
```

Let me explain why you are getting the problem.  Say you have 2 words out of 5, 2nd and 5th having length less than 3.  So you have to remove 2 strings form the "wordzList".  Say you removed 2nd one, now the list size is 4 and last available value is at index 3.  When you are looking for the 5th string which was at array index 4, you are trying to remove the non existing element from the list.  List last index is 3, but you are trying to remove the element at index 4.  Hope you under the flaw.  Think about the logic to overcome.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0; i < wordzList.size(); i++)
{
    if(wordzList.get(i).length() < 3){
        wordzList.remove(i);
        i--;
     }
}
// Use the ArrayList from now on - so then next line is iffy. 
wordz = wordzList.toArray(new String[wordzList.size()]);
```

The problem results from looking at the array while you modify the parallel ArrayList. Stick with one data structure at a time.

Avoid arrays - ArrayLists provide better service (as you have found out),.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://javadocs.com/docs/oracle/jdk/7u45/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.java)? Try checking the dimensions of the array. This is usually thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index...

Comment: "usually"? Are there "unusual" cases where this Exception will be thrown?